# How to save a canvas having more than one image to the picture library in windows store app using c# and xaml

Tags: xaml, canvas, windows-store-apps

I am creating an application for windows 8 store app using c# and xaml.I have used a canvas where more than one images are added now i want t save the canvas to the picture library .

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131089/screenshot-with-xaml-and-c-sharp/19131419#19131419

Comment: The above link is  refering for Windows 8.1 .I need it for Windows 8

Comment: Maybe some third party . need to give a search.

Comment: You'll have better luck converting to 8.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinRT XAML Toolkit's Composition library. Build your UI as you would to display on screen, call `Measure` and `Arrange` on the root element to size it to your output image dimensions and use one of the extension methods - `WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render()` or `.RenderToPngStream()` to render to a `WriteableBitmap` or `MemoryStream` respectively. You can then save the bitmap or stream to a file if you enable pictures library access capability in your app's manifest.

Comment: Filip I am trying with RenderToPngStream as bellow                                                                  var canvas = cvPicFrame as FrameworkElement;
   MemoryStream t1 = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.RenderToPngStream(canvas);
   byte[] st = t1.ToArray();
but i am getting the following error

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: HRESULT: [0x88990015], Module: [SharpDX.Direct2D1], ApiCode: [D2DERR_WRONG_RESOURCE_DOMAIN/WrongResourceDomain], Message: The resource was realized on the wrong render target.

Comment: Filip it will be very helpful if you will response to this

Comment: Any solution with this error ? I have the same error in my code. Looks like the problem is with the ImageRenderer class:

var bitmap = await image.Source.ToSharpDX(renderTarget);
 renderTarget.DrawBitmap(
                    bitmap,
                    rect,
                    (float)image.Opacity,
                    D2D.BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);

But I have no idea how to fix this..

Answer (score 0):

I lost so much time trying to render UI elements using SharpDX and WinRt toolkit without any results, after which found that there exists a very nice class:     RenderTargetBitmap, which can be used for such tasks.
Here is a code snippet copeid from this web site
http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/11/05/render-the-screen-of-a-windows-store-app-to-a-bitmap-in-windows-8-1/comment-page-1

```
async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CaptureToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement  uielement, IRandomAccessStream stream, Guid encoderId)
{
   try
   {
  var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
  await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

  var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

  var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
  var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
  encoder.SetPixelData(
      BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
      BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
      (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
      (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
      logicalDpi,
      logicalDpi,
      pixels.ToArray());

  await encoder.FlushAsync();

  return renderTargetBitmap;
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
   DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
}

return null;
}
```